# What is a concise and clear idiom for mapping values into a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

A relatively common task is to need to assign ("map") a manual value to each row based on a lookup into a small map.

In `data.table` the most obvious ways of doing this create very convoluted code, and so I wonder if I'm missing an idiom that produces this result with clearer coding.

Consider this example, where we start with a large `data.table` that has a `Name` column containing either `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`.

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(ID = 1:4000, Name = rep(letters[1:4],1000), X = rnorm(4000))
setkey(DT, ID)
```

We now want to assign the scores (a = 1, b = 4, c = 6, d = 3) in an extra column.  Perhaps, joining to a small table like this:

```
Weights = data.table(Name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), W = c(1,4,6,3))

setkey(DT, Name)
setkey(Weights, Name)

DT = Weights[DT]
```

However note that we have had to much up the index for DT to do this and the columns are reordered.  So the job is not complete until we do:

```
setkey(DT, ID)
setcolorder(DT, c("ID", "Name", "X", "W"))
```

And even though this has got there in the end the weight setting is problematic because the values and names are not joined together, which is asking for a typo.  Something like this would be better:

```
WeightList = list(a = 1, b = 3, c = 6, d = 3)
```

But how can we then look up from this list into DT?

At first glance it looks like we can do

```
DT[, W := WeightList[Name]]

> DT
        ID Name           X W
   1:    1    a -0.05006513 1
   2:    2    b  0.01637769 3
   3:    3    c  2.18922366 6
   4:    4    d  0.18327623 3
   5:    5    a -1.44108171 1
  ---                        
3996: 3996    d  0.70507702 3
3997: 3997    a  0.42989246 1
3998: 3998    b  1.31611236 3
3999: 3999    c -1.43431163 6
4000: 4000    d  0.32244477 3
```

But that W column is not well formed, and simple operations on it don't work

```
> DT[, W + 1]
Error in W + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: So just use `c` instead of `list`? As in `WeightList = c(a = 1, b = 3, c = 6, d = 3)`? I think your solution is great btw.

Comment: D'oh, I'm such an idiot not spotting that.  A really nice answer to this question would be to say "use `c`" and then explain what is going on that means c works and list doesn't.  I don't really understand why one works and not the other.

Comment: Because `WeightList` is a `list` and you are subsetting from it and then assigning a `list` column to `DT`, just see what happens when you do `WeightList = list(a = 1, b = 3, c = 6, d = 3) ; head(WeightList[DT$Name])`

Comment: @DavidArenburg if you put that as an answer I'll accept it.  Not sure there is more to be said on the matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `on` argument along with `:=` was designed with these cases in mind, i.e., no need to reorder (setting key for join) and copy the entire data.table (when you don't use `:=`) just to add column(s).

```
require(data.table)
DT = data.table(ID = 1:4000, Name = rep(letters[1:4],1000), X = rnorm(4000))
setkey(DT, ID)
Weights = data.table(Name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), W = c(1,4,6,3))

DT[Weights, W := W, on="Name"]
key(DT) # [1] "ID"
```

`DT` is updated by reference, and key is retained.

Comment: I'm advocating to use more verbose `W := i.W` option ;)

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning a `list` column to `DT` and hence can't add integers to it (without using `unlist` first at least).

You could change your `list` vector to a usual `integer`/`numeric` *named* vector and your code will work just fine. For instance

```
WeightList <- c(a = 1, b = 3, c = 6, d = 3)
```

Or a bit more robust method creating this vector could be

```
WeightList <- setNames(c(1, 3, 6, 3), letters[1:4])
```

Then, your code as before

```
DT[, W := WeightList[Name]]
```

Comment: Why is the second form "more robust"?  Surely it is more robust to have the assignment between the letters and the values.  If I add in x = 4, then I have no risk of messing things up, but adding x and 4 into vectors could easily go wrong.

Comment: I thought it is more robust in a sense that you don't need to write `=` so many times. And match each one against the other. Of course if the letters are random, it won't be the solution.